# Server side rendering not work on production build Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to deploy my Next.js app to my own hosting. I run `next export` to build the app, it works and i able to run it on my hosting server. But the problem is the app not server side rendering (reloading the app on any page except main page will cause error):

[image]

I'm new on Next.js and my previous apps on react can't do server side rendering, so i a bit confuse about it. Any help will be welcome, Thank You!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please provide more details.

Comment: @subashMahapatra not found error, i already edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, `next export` is for exporting your project into static HTML. More importantly, [the docs state](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) (emphasis mine):

> `next export` is intended for scenarios where **none of your pages have**
> **server-side or incremental data requirements** (though
> statically-rendered pages can still [fetch data on the client side](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fetching-data-on-the-client-side)
> just fine).
>
> If you're looking to make a hybrid site where only some pages are
> prerendered to static HTML, Next.js already does that automatically
> for you! Read up on [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization) for details.
>
> `next export` also causes features like Incremental Static Generation
> and Regeneration to be disabled, as they require next start or a
> serverless deployment to function.

This means that if your routes need server-side data fetching with `getServerSideProps`, you'll need to do run the project as a Node.js server either [through Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#nodejs-server) (`next build && next start`), or with a [custom node server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server).

Comment: oh okay, i think i miss that static part documentation. maybe i will try another method to deploy it. thank you btw!

Comment: @cbr can you confirm if wildcard routes would work this way? Like if I have a route "abc/:def", and I fetch details depending on the value of "def" on client side, will `next export` throw an error?